# JList Listener cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Trying to add a LIstSelectionListener and keep getting error cannot find symbol ListSelectionListener()
^
symbol class ListSelectionListener

```
jlstExtras.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            int[] indices = jlstExtras.getSelectedIndices();

            int i;
            for( i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){
                if(indices[i] == 0)
                    delivery = 4.00;
                else if (indices[i] == 1)
                    tip = .15;
                else if (indices[i] == 2)
                    tip = .20;

            }       

        }
    });
```

error is in the first line part (new ListSelectionListener()

Comment: Have you imported javax.swing.event package contents and what is you java version? it should be 1.4 or higher

Comment: yeah i have import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

Comment: i guess i was missing one needed the .event package aswell

Comment: you don't have import javax.swing.event.*;